# Set Number Format for dynamic parameters in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

One of the parameters in my Crystal Report is a year.  When the report runs, the years appear in a listbox of values formatted with a comma in the thousands place, like 2,010 instead of 2010.  How can I change the number format of a dynamic parameter?

The data type of my year parameter is 'Number,' and I have the default number format (file/options/fields/number/number/customize/number/thousands separator) box unchecked.

Is that something I can change?

Thanks for any help.

Also, the year parameter value is not displayed on the report, it's used as selection criteria, so that's not what I'm trying to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Comment: if you posted a screen shot, I'm not seeing it.  thx- seeing it now, but can't get there from parameter/edit

Comment: ??? - Not sure why the image isn't showing, but... When you open the .RPT file and right-click on the number field on the report, do you get "Format Object" as one of your popup menu options?

Comment: that website is blocked from work.  The year isn't on the report, it's a parameter, so there's nothing to right-click on.

Comment: Oh... I see... It's happening dynamically when it fills the list box... It's a lot of changes, but could you change the type to 4 char string (in the sql for the report)?

Comment: OK, I had a view so I changed my datasources to use that view and cast'ed the smallint year to char(4) in the view.  That worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can add new formula field and set this formula for example:

---

"some string " + ToText ({@Year5},"0000" )

---

Note:

- ToText : string method.
- {@Year5}: return number of year;
- "0000":   formated number